# Is Laravel/Homestead can be used on other PHP frameworks?

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, homestead

I am not yet used Laravel and I am just curios if the Homestead can be used on other PHP frameworks like CodeIgniter?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/using-homestead-with-other-frameworks

Comment: Thanks @GluePear and sorry for not googling it first. already a habit :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple google search would have answered this question

Answer (score 0):

Homestead runs on Ubuntu within a Virtual Machine. It comes with the following software installed:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Git
- PHP 7.0
- HHVM
- Nginx
- MySQL
- Sqlite3
- Postgres
- Composer
- Node (With PM2, Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
- Redis
- Memcached
- Beanstalkd

Pretty much anything a webserver needs to run any kind of PHP framework. If there's something missing for the framework you're using, you can install it.

Answer (score -1):

You can of course use it for any php related project. But be careful when configuring the `Homestead.yaml` file to correctly set the path to your projects.

```
sites:
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public
    - map: codeigniter.api
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/codeigniter
```

You can also setup multiple databases if you need to.

Simply don't forget to run `bash init.sh` and `vagrant provision` each time you modify the config file.

Comment: You shouldn't run `bash init.sh` each time you modify the `Homestead.yaml` file, only run `vagrant provision`.